# How to reshape the specific columns of data table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I was working on reshaping the table, found out it's more complicated than I thought.

The original data is

```
                                |----- Category 1----------------|----- Category 2-----------------|
         Date     ID    Cycle   Type 1   Type 2   Type 3  Type 4  Type 1   Type 2   Type 3   Type 4
0      Somedate   1      1        v1       v2      v3        v4       v5      v6      v7       v8
1      Somedate          2        v9       v10     v11       v12      v13     v14     v15      v16
2      Somedate          3        v17      v18     v19       v20      v21     v22     v23      v24
3      Somedate   2      1        c1       c2      c3        c4       c5      c6      c7       c8   
4      Somedate          2        c9       c10     c11       c12      c13     c14     c15      c16
5      Somedate          3        c17      c18     c19       c20      c21     c22     c23      c24
```

what I'd like to do is

```
         Date     ID     Category   Type    Cycle 1   Cycle 2   Cycle 3
0      Somedate   1         1      Type 1     v1        v9       v17
1      Somedate   1         1      Type 2     v2       v10       v18
0      Somedate   1         1      Type 3     v3       v11       v19
0      Somedate   1         1      Type 4     v4       v12       v20
0      Somedate   1         2      Type 1     v5       v13       v21
0      Somedate   1         2      Type 2     v6       v14       v22
0      Somedate   1         2      Type 3     v7       v15       v23
0      Somedate   1         2      Type 4     v8       v16       v24
```

and continues for ID = 2

The basic idea is to keep the Date and ID columns, expand and transpose Categories and Types.

The data originally looks like this:
[csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LhINsTbxXYgItfE6N-Sg_bBghj0f6hJj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. What exactly do you mean by "in the shape of". Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You are probably looking for some version of [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt) but its hard to help you with a concrete solution if I don't have the exact same dataframe. Most importantly, I need to know whether you have a multindex as columns

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the advice. My data is read from the csv file and currently, I cannot access the that data so it takes time to produce something similar to what I need help with. For the multiindex, no I do not need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have more columns than just `Cycle` and `Type` you can not simply use transpose but need to stack  `Type` and pivot `Cycle`. Additionally it gets more complicated because you have a hierarchical index with `Category` (two lines with indices are hierarchical whether you think you need it or not) and a bunch of missing fields.

I have to guess how you want to treat all that. I read your data with

```
In [28]: df = pd.read_csv('../Downloads/stackoverflow.csv', header=1).rename(columns={'A1': 'A1.0', 'A4': 'A4.0', 'A7': 'A7.0', 'E0': 'E0.0', 'E1': 'E1.0'})                                               

In [29]: df['ID'].ffill(inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                                      

In [30]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[30]: 
          Date   ID  Cycle    A1.0  A4.0  A7.0    E0.0  E1.0  A1.1  A4.1  A7.1   E0.1  E1.1  A1.2  A4.2  A7.2   E0.2  E1.2  A1.3  A4.3  A7.3   E0.3  E1.3
0   2021-01-14  1.0      1   124.0     8     9     8.0    96    90     8  1235   62.0    98    90     8  1235   62.0    98    90     8  1235   62.0    98
1   2021-01-15  1.0      2   127.0    76   987     NaN    86     8     6   234    NaN   234     8     6   234    NaN   234     8     6   234    NaN   234
2   2021-01-16  1.0      3     0.3  7869     9    22.0    48     8     0     7   67.0     2     8     0     7   67.0     2     8     0     7   67.0     2
3   2021-01-17  1.0      4   809.0    89     8    89.0     0    34    23   529  651.0  6929    34    23   529  651.0  6929    34    23   529  651.0  6929
4   2021-01-18  2.0      1   245.0    65    97     5.0     3     7     7   978   75.0  7857     7     7   978   75.0  7857     7     7   978   75.0  7857
5   2021-01-19  2.0      2   744.0    76   345   768.0    78     7    76   756  675.0  7692     7    76   756  675.0  7692     7    76   756  675.0  7692
6   2021-01-20  2.0      3     3.0     4    32     NaN    34     6  3456    34   37.0    37     6  3456    34   37.0    37     6  3456    34   37.0    37
7   2021-01-21  2.0      4     7.0     7  9781     1.0     2     3    64     7   75.0    54     3    64     7   75.0    54     3    64     7   75.0    54
8   2021-01-22  3.0      1     6.0   123   854   584.0    13    46    56    54   54.0     2    46    56    54   54.0     2    46    56    54   54.0     2
9   2021-01-23  3.0      2  1515.0     3     1   146.0    14     1     6  3456    2.0    45     1     6  3456    2.0    45     1     6  3456    2.0    45
10  2021-01-24  3.0      3   412.0   461    46  1461.0  4613   146    61     1   56.0     7   146    61     1   56.0     7   146    61     1   56.0     7
11  2021-01-24  3.0      4    54.0     7   889     2.0     1    17   177   571    1.0     5    17   177   571    1.0     5    17   177   571    1.0     5
```

Ignoring the category and exploiting that pandas by default will deduplicate column names with a suffix. If that is not what you wanted, you should have provided a reproducible example ;)

Then to unwrangle category from types split the `Types` from the `Category` suffix with `pd.wide_to_long` pull the `Types` into the index and then reset the index:

```
In [32]: df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['A1', 'A4', 'A7', 'E0', 'E1'], i=['Date', 'ID', 'Cycle'], j='Category', sep='.')                                                                                   
Out[32]: 
                                  A1   A4    A7    E0  E1
Date       ID  Cycle Category                            
2021-01-14 1.0 1     0         124.0    8     9   8.0  96
                     1          90.0    8  1235  62.0  98
                     2          90.0    8  1235  62.0  98
                     3          90.0    8  1235  62.0  98
2021-01-15 1.0 2     0         127.0   76   987   NaN  86
...                              ...  ...   ...   ...  ..
2021-01-24 3.0 3     3         146.0   61     1  56.0   7
               4     0          54.0    7   889   2.0   1
                     1          17.0  177   571   1.0   5
                     2          17.0  177   571   1.0   5
                     3          17.0  177   571   1.0   5

In [41]: df2.columns.rename('Type', inplace=True)

In [48]: df3 = df2.stack().reset_index()                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[48]: 
           Date   ID  Cycle  Category Type      0
0    2021-01-14  1.0      1         0   A1  124.0
1    2021-01-14  1.0      1         0   A4    8.0
2    2021-01-14  1.0      1         0   A7    9.0
3    2021-01-14  1.0      1         0   E0    8.0
4    2021-01-14  1.0      1         0   E1   96.0
..          ...  ...    ...       ...  ...    ...
230  2021-01-24  3.0      4         3   A1   17.0
231  2021-01-24  3.0      4         3   A4  177.0
232  2021-01-24  3.0      4         3   A7  571.0
233  2021-01-24  3.0      4         3   E0    1.0
234  2021-01-24  3.0      4         3   E1    5.0
```

Now this starts to look like a proper DataFrame. This is known as `long format`. To transform this to your desired output you only need a pivot operation

```
In [52]: df3.pivot(index=['Date', 'ID', 'Category', 'Type'], columns='Cycle', values=0)                                                                                                                    
Out[52]: 
Cycle                             1   2      3      4
Date       ID  Category Type                         
2021-01-14 1.0 0        A1    124.0 NaN    NaN    NaN
                        A4      8.0 NaN    NaN    NaN
                        A7      9.0 NaN    NaN    NaN
                        E0      8.0 NaN    NaN    NaN
                        E1     96.0 NaN    NaN    NaN
...                             ...  ..    ...    ...
2021-01-24 3.0 3        A1      NaN NaN  146.0   17.0
                        A4      NaN NaN   61.0  177.0
                        A7      NaN NaN    1.0  571.0
                        E0      NaN NaN   56.0    1.0
                        E1      NaN NaN    7.0    5.0
```

In the example you provided a bunch of cycles were not measured on any given date, that's where all your `NaN` stem from. Also stack drops missing values by default, you might need to adjust that, the Category starts counting at 0 and probably a few more minor details need to be adjusted.

I hope this gets you started on the right track. Your question in itself is solved by a simple pivot operation, but the data wrangling to get you csv into something thats actually usable is not trivial. You might want to read a bit about [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) (the link is in R, but the concept is still important).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! The actual data is not identical as what I posted on the question (it's actually more messy), but I get how  to do it!